# Access values from SOAP client response

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap-client

```
//Create the client object
$soapclient = new SoapClient( 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL' );

// Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in the associative array.
$params = array( 'CountryName' => 'Spain' );
$response = $soapclient->GetCitiesByCountry( $params );

var_dump( $response );

foreach ( $response as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value;
}
```

By using foreach i am getting all string in a `$value` like

```
SpainFuerteventura / Aeropuerto
SpainHierro / Aeropuerto
...
```

How do i can get all country names in one array and all city names in another array?

sample: `var_dump( $response );`

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'GetCitiesByCountryResult' => string '<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Fuerteventura / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Hierro / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>La Palma / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Las Palmas De Gran Canaria / Gando</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Lanzarote / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country'... (length=4383)
```

Comment: I am not sure with your question? do you want to break the string into array ?

Comment: yes into array. like `<Country>` tag values in one array and `<City>` in another.

Comment: `$response->GetCitiesByCountryResult` contains that XML string. Use an XML parser to process it.

Comment: @Barmar this one  SimpleXML?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very clean, but a short and simple solution, since there always is just one country in the response, I suppose (if not, you could use `preg_split` instead of `explode` below):

```
// get the response as a string, strip all tags but <Country>
$raw = strip_tags($response->GetCitiesByCountryResult,"<Country>");

// use the Country tag as delimiter
$cities = explode("<Country>$params[CountryName]</Country>",$raw);

// get rid of heading and trailing spaces
$cities = array_map("trim",$cities);
```

The [SoapClient PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) might be handy. If the XML structure were more complex, than SimpleXML or [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parser would be universal solution (as Barmar suggests in the comment).